# docker with sudo permission only able to access from internet

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am using amazon linux 2 , a EC2 Instance.

When i run

> sudo docker run -p 3006:80 nginx

I able to access the nginx welcome page http://EC2_IP:3006

But when i run **without** sudo

> docker run -p 3006:80 nginx

I could not access the same from http://EC2_IP:3006

- I added ec2-user to the docker group

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: `sudo` or not shouldn't make a difference here; if you can successfully run that `docker` command, the Docker daemon will actually start the container and the mechanics of this are identical.  Those two commands do exactly the same thing once they open the `/var/run/docker.sock` Unix socket file.

Comment: in both cases, container successfully running, only difference is, sudo container -  able to see the output in browser, non sudo container - connection refused